# Laravel 4: Updating a user

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to update the password of a user I've pulled from the database in Laravel 4.  Here is what I have:

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)->get();
if (!empty($user)) {
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);
    $user->save();
}
```

But Laravel is telling me `save` is an unknown method.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8):

`get` returns an array of users. You need to use `first` to get a single user object that will allow you to adjust the password and save the record.

```php
if ($user = User::where('username', $username)->first())
{
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);

    $user->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `$user` actually has a 'user' in it?

It wont be 'empty' - it will be BOOL `false`. Try `var_dump($user)` and confirm something is returned?

Try this:

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)->get();
var_dump($user);
if ($user) {
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);
    $user->save();
}
```